# SED command to remove trailing white spaces

Tags: sed

Is there a `sed` command to remove trailing white spaces?

Answer (score 11):

use the command below:

```
sed 's/\s*$//g' your_file
```

Comment: Use - `sed -i 's/\s*$//g' file_name` to update the file directly